# Hive property not getting set

Tags: hive, hive-configuration

I am setting the following property in hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name>
  <value>nonstrict</value>
</property>
```

However in hive console if I run, `show conf "hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode";`, I get `strict`

Does anybody have any clues as to why my configuration properties in hive-site.xml are not overriding the default properties? Further, I also tried to set this property from the console by using the `set` command, but with no luck there either.

Comment: Note: I tried to change the property `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode` to `nonstrict` in `hive-default.xml.template`. Even after doing that  `show conf "hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode";` returns `strict`. Could this be anyhow related to me using mysql for the metastore_db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is happening why SHOW CONF doesn't show the current property's values that command show the default value.

Check this documentation

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowConf

Regards

Answer (score 2):

To see the current value of a configuration setting, run the `set [property]` command without specifying a new value.  For example:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode;
```

The `show conf` command displays the default value, required type, and description, but it does not display the current value.